# Can an object not have a method __dir__()?

Tags: python

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be called and must return the list of attributes.

Since all classes are somehow descendants of the `object` class, which has the `__dir__()` method, how can any instance of any class not have this method?

I know I can override this method, but I'm confused by the phrase. What exactly does this mean?

Comment: Probably legacy wording.

Comment: @roganjosh in earlier versions, did inheritance work differently or was the method not defined for the `object` class?

Comment: In Python 2, custom classes do not inherit `object` by default.

Comment: If you bind an object's `__dir__` to something other than a method object (e.g. `my_obj.__dir__ = 123`), `dir` will ignore it. That may be what the docs are trying to indicate.

Comment: every class instance will automatically inherit the `__dir__()` method from the `object` class. But, if you wish to customize the behavior of the `__dir__()` method for a specific class, you can choose to override it in your own class!!!

Comment: I don't know if there are any objects in Python3 that don't have `__dir__` by default, but you can remove it with `del Class.__dir__`. Perhaps this behavior of the dir function persists for historical reasons (i.e., it hasn't changed since Python 2), and the documentation simply explains its specification as is.

Comment: IIRC correctly from a podcast,`dir(foo)` is intended to list the “interesting” attributes of foo in an informational context (say the REPL).  (not sure what would qualify as not interesting).  Therefore implementing your own `__dir__` allows you to control that list, of what’s “interesting”.  None of the mechanisms wrt inheritance and `object` seem all that particular to this method.

Comment: Is it possible for a type implemented in C to not inherit from `object`? I've never dabbled in that myself.